# "Indexed name is not a std_logic_vector"

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I am trying to use "port map" in my code, but I don't know how to fix an error. It says "indexed name is not a std_logic_vector" for both port map. I have to implement the circuit below.[image]

I did the counter and the MPG and added them as components, they work separately. I will leave the code for the circuit. It says that it is a problem at "port map".

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity test_env is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           btn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           sw : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           led : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end test_env;

architecture Behavioral of test_env is
component MPG
    Port(clk : in STD_LOGIC;
         btn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
         enable : out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component counter
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           btn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           sw : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           led: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end component;
signal en: STD_LOGIC;
signal s: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
signal dcd: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
begin
    --led<=sw;
    --an<=btn(3 downto 0);
    --cat<=(others=>'0');
    process(s)
    begin
        case s is 
            when "000" => dcd<="00000001";
            when "001" => dcd<="00000010";
            when "010" => dcd<="00000100";
            when "011" => dcd<="00001000";
            when "100" => dcd<="00010000";
            when "101" => dcd<="00100000";
            when "110" => dcd<="01000000";
            when others => dcd<="10000000";
        end case;
    end process;
    
    monopulse: MPG port map(clk, btn, en);
   count: counter port map(clk, btn, sw(0), s);
    led(7 downto 0)<= dcd;  
end Behavioral;
```

I will leave the codes for the components too

Counter(16 bits)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity counter is
   Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           btn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           sw : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           led: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end counter;

architecture Behavioral of counter is
signal Q: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
begin
    process(btn)
    begin
       if rising_edge(clk) then
          if(btn(0)='1') then 
            if(sw(0)='1') then
                Q<= Q + "0000000000000001";
            else Q<=Q - "0000000000000001";
            end if;
           end if;
        end if;
     end process;
     led<=Q;
end Behavioral;
```

MPG

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity MPG is
    Port(clk : in STD_LOGIC;
         btn : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
         enable : out STD_LOGIC);
end MPG;

architecture Behavioral of MPG is
signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal Q1 : STD_LOGIC;
signal Q2 : STD_LOGIC;
signal Q3 : STD_LOGIC;
begin
    enable<=Q2 and (not(Q3));
    process(btn)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            count<=count + "0000000000000001";
        end if;
        end process;
    
    process(btn)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if count(15 downto 0)= "1111111111111111" then
                Q1<=btn(1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    process(btn)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            Q2<=Q1;
            Q3<=Q2;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

If anyone can help me, thank you very much!!

Comment: `count: counter port map(clk, btn, sw(0), s);` the third argument, which is indexed,  is not a std_logic_vector (exactly as the message says) but a std_logic. Now compare that with what the "counter" component declaration expects ... `sw : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you happen to know how to link the exit from MPG which is `std_logic` to the entrance `btn` of the counter which is `std_logic_vector`? How to memorise that one significant bit?

Comment: The various entity port interfaces don't match the small schematic image included here. SW, BTN ,  CLK and the unnamed enable are shown as single nets, the counter output is shown to be a composite net with three elements and LEDs hast eight. Consider making your port interfaces conform.

Comment: Since the counter only uses sw(0), why not make the sw port a std_logic?